# Firebase Auth updateEmail, updatePassword method goes into an infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, oauth

setting up auth with firebase has been super simple and can't be happier.
but I am trying to add some extra methods to update a user's info like email and password.

However, when I use these methods, the function that is executing my firebase code goes into an infinite loop. here are my functions:

```
  function updateEmail(email) {
    const user = auth.currentUser;
    console.log(user);
    console.log(email);

    updateEmail(user, "user@example.com").then(() => {
    console.log('success!')

  }).catch((error) => {
    console.log('error')

  });

  }
```

```
  function updatePassword() {
  console.log('updatePassword')
  const user = auth.currentUser;
  const newPassword = 'asdf'

  updatePassword(user, newPassword).then(() => {
    console.log('success')
  }).catch((error) => {
    // An error ocurred
    // ...
}); }
```

when I sign in with google, email link, facebook and pass/emaiil,
i have not had this problem, What could be the problem here?

Comment: Can you try changing the names of the functions. Since you are using the same function names as the firebase functions it will keep looping.

Comment: ok this works thank you so much, but now i have this error:  FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/requires-recent-login).

Comment: In which function will this occur?